# Replacing a character on a page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<h1><b>Headline:</b> something</h1>
```

and I want to get rid of the colon (:) on the page.

What's the easiest way to do it with jQuery? I'm a JS newbie so please provide the entire code what I need to insert in the head-tag.

Thanks!

Comment: Please build my website for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `:` if it is last character in `<b>`:

```
$('h1 b').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.replace(/:$/, '');
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/YGVDf/))

Comment: @Kai It needs to be wrapped in the [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (as do all other examples on this page): `$(function() { ... });` Updated demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/YGVDf/1/).

Comment: thanks for your help. it works! sorry for being such an amateur. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
var b = $('b:contains(\:)');
b.html(b.html().replace('\:', ''));
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ULvrh/)

Comment: thanks! :) how can I specify it to the `<b>` tag in the H1 only? And how to I insert it into the page? Just `<script>` tags around it?

Comment: @Kai Use a selector the same way as you'd have done in CSS: `$('h1 b:contains(\:)');` or `$('h1 > b:contains(\:)');`

Comment: To everyone else: This only replaces the first instance of a colon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('h1 b').html().replace(':','');
```

Comment: .. no you can't .. (*i mean, you **can** do that, but it doesn't do what the OP is asking for*)

Comment: No, not really. This *will* replace a `:` with an empty string within the HTML of `h1 b`, *but* the string is never assigned back to the `<b>` element.